What does 緩急 exactly mean?

寛いでいても、日向油断なく左右へ視線を配る。


どうしても抜けないのだ。空間を満たす、妙な重たい雰囲気が。


何かに似ているのだけれど、一体何だろう。身体に纏わりついて、緩急があって、引っ張られるような

The character is in a horror setting and he thinks this...

何かに似ているのだけれど、一体何だろう

I understand this part.

身体に纏わりついて、緩急があって、引っ張られるような

and I understand here it says it coils around the boy and it's like being pulled...
But what does 緩急があって here mean? The are fluctuations?

What is this from? The quoted part doesn't exactly establish a scene by itself. If it's a novel, what is the title?

緩急がある means something is sometimes fast/active and sometimes slow/calm. In this context, he is probably saying the eerie sensation is "coming in waves".
